# How to check if Firebase DynamicLink is already shortened and there is no need to shorten it again?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-dynamic-links

This is my simple function:

```
import FirebaseDynamicLinks
   
let url = URL(string: "https://joyone.page.link/pXJG7y5kLPgxoTyg6?title=Klub+Innowator%C3%B3w+OPZZ")
let prefix = "https://joyone.page.link"
DynamicLinkComponents(link: url, domainURIPrefix: prefix)?.shorten { [weak self] url, _, error in
    print(url) // https://joyone.page.link/wZiUKDego5EmFY6VA
    print(error) // nil
}
```

This function should return error `Cannot shorten a short Dynamic Link` but it does not. It works on library for Android... but not on ios.

on Android library there is an error returned:

```
Cannot shorten a short Dynamic Link: https://joyone.page.link/pXJG7y5kLPgxoTyg6?title=Klub+Innowator%C3%B3w+OPZZ
```

Comment: what method is your Android Team using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another method for this:

```
DynamicLinkComponents.shortenURL(url, options: nil) { [weak self] url, _, error in
    // here you receive a specific error if link is already shortened
}
```